# Good media catalogue for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, multimedia

I have a lot of Audio CDs, DVDs, Data CDs/ DVDs containing audio/ video media like MP3 files or mp4 files, etc.

Could you please recommend some software that will index this media and let me search the database? So, I can tell DVD1 contains this movie and Data DVD4 contains this mp4 file, etc.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04, more specifically, gnome 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Catalog your Discs (& Folders/Drives) with CD Cat, A nice little media catalog program for keeping track of your data CDs and DVDs.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install cdcat
```

Also you may take a look at Removable media catalog managment.

> GWhere allows to manage a database of yours CDs and others removable
>   media (hard disks, floppy drive, Zip drive, CD-ROM, etc...). With
>   GWhere it's easy to browse yours CDs or to make quick search without
>   need to insert yours CDs in the drive at each once.<sup>Ubuntu Apps</sup>

To install, just click [**GWhere** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gwhere/)